# install php7 alongside php5 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have installed php 5 as my main version on Ubuntu 15.04 which I use to develop my current projects. I want to install php 7 alongside php 5 is there a way to install both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed php7 alongside php5 with the help of vagrant
follow the link below to get php 7
https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev